# LaTeX jumbled up when printing

Tags: bug, mathjax, export

when printing pages on math.stackexchange, 
often the LaTeX equations become jumbled up. 
Sometimes the error is minor misalignment, sometimes it is more serious.

For me, this occurs both on IE and Chrome. The jumbling only happens for printing. Viewing is perfectly fine.

Anyone facing this problem?

Also, any possible solutions?

Comment: A similar question: [printing pages from m.s.e.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/printing-pages-from-m-s-e).
Probably also some other questions tagged [meta-tag:export] might be of interest for you.

Comment: It would likely help in diagnosing and solving the problem if you posted scans of what your printouts look like - "jumbled" is not specific enough. In general, it's best to provide as much information as possible; for example, consider [my recent bug post about a font issue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9089/264).

Comment: thanks for the comments. I have more or less abandoned printing directly from the browser. I just discovered stackprinter.com, it works perfectly.

Comment: You might try switching the MathJax renderer to SVG (if you are using IE, you need to be IE9 or later).  This tends to print better than the HTML-CSS mode.